# Find k-th smallest number of a subsequence in a circular array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Hi I am trying to solve this problem from IEEEXtreme 2014:

You are given N integers that are arranged circularly. There are N ways to pick consecutive subsequences of length M (M < N). For any such subsequence we can find the “K”-value of that subsequence. “K”-value for a given subsequence is the K-th smallest number in that subsequence. Given the array of N, find the smallest K-value of all possible subsequences. For example N=5 M=3 K=2 and the array 1 5 3 4 2 give the result 2.

My approach is first I create a sorted array list which inserts the new input in the correct position. I add the first M integers into the list. Record the K-th smallest value. Then I keep removing the oldest integer and adding the next integer into the list and comparing the new K-th value with the old one. This is my sorted array list.

```
class SortedArrayList extends ArrayList {  
    public void insertSorted(int value) {        
        for (int i = size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            if( value - (Integer)get(i)>=0){            
                    add(i+1,new Integer(value));
                    return;
            }
        }
        add(0,new Integer(value));
    }
}
```

I think this brute-force method is not efficient but not able to come up with any ideas yet. Do you know any better solutions for this ? Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to understand how this is different than finding kth smallest number in a array. Did I miss something?

Comment: For example, N=5 M=2 K=2 and the array 1 5 5 2 3 give the sub-sequences 1 5 , 5 5, 5 2, 2 3, 3 1 and the result is 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient solution:

1. Let's get rid of circularity to keep things simpler. We can do it by appending the given array to itself.
2. We can assume that all numbers in the input are unique. If it is not the case, we may use a pair `(element, position)` instead of each element.
3. Let's sort the given array. Now we will use the binary search over the answer(that is, the position of the `k`-th smallest element among all subarrays in the sorted global array).
4. How to check that a fixed candidate `x` is at least as large as the `k-th` smallest number? Let's mark all positions of the numbers less than or equal to `x` with `1` and the rest with `0`. Now we just need to check if there is a subarray of length `M` that contains at least `k` ones. We can do it in linear time using rolling sums.

The time complexity is: `O(N log N)` for sorting the input + `O(N log N)` for binary search over the answer(there are `O(log N)` checks and each of them is done in linear time as described in 4.). Thus, the total time complexity is `O(N log N)`.

P.S. I can think of several other solutions with the same time complexity, but this one seems to be the simplest one to implement(it does not require any custom data structures).

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution for the problem with the circular array would be to simply use modulo. So, if you're just looking for a solution for simulating a circular array, i would suggest something like this:

```
int n = somevalue;//the startingpoint of the subsequence
int m = someothervalue;//the index in the subsequence

int absolute_index = (n + m) % N;
```

where N is the total number of elements in the sequence.

Next step towards more efficiency would be to store the index of the k-th value. This way, you'd only have to calculate a new K-Value every M-th step (worst case) and simply compare it to one new value per every other step. 
But i'll leave that to you ;)